# Help me with my Bhut Jolokia

Tags: chili

I have a Bhut Jolokia that is supposed to be red but now turned from green to a chocolate brown and the pots are already becoming softer.

Did i may get cross-polinated Seeds and a Chocolate Bhut Jolokia or do they still turn red?

The form of the chili pepper is totally Jolokia with the long warty devils tong like shape

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking and worse without a picture.

Comment: Always put a picture if it's feasible. Helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Photograph might be useful, but essentially no, they won't go red now, it sounds as if you have the so called chocolate version of Bhut Jolokia, which produces brown pods; if you bought the seeds, you were sold the wrong ones. If they're seeds you kept yourself and they were pollinated outdoors last year, in the open, then you can't guarantee that the red ones you grew outdoors last year will produce seed that is the same as themselves, because they don't come true. Best to pick and use these chocolate ones rather than wait for them to go either mouldy or shrivel up completely.